# Who decides which form of a word is colloquial and which one is not?

Tags: стилистика

I often see people here reasoning about what sounds colloquial to them and what doesn't which has its implications on the decision of someone who's asking for help.

Who defines what is colloquial and what isn't?

Is there an authority that maintains the Russian language standard?

Comment: What's the actual question here? There is certainly not going to be a definite authority on what is colloquial.

Comment: If there is no authority, how come anybody can agree on that. If a certain word is considered colloquial in a metropolitan city, but in a provincial town it is quite what everybody says what would be a resolution on that. More general, is there an exact definition of what colloquial is? When is it appropriate to label a word colloquial? If the notion of colloquial isn't well defined what do people mean by using it?

Comment: This question (being too broad and formulated as an invitation to discussion) is beyond the scope of this site. With Russian, Russian Language Institute, the official regulator of Russian, does decide what is colloquial and what is not.

Comment: @Quassnoi Isn't that a valid answer?

Comment: @Alenanno: it would probably be on linguistics.SO if formulated just with copying subject. Currently it looks like an illustration to "I would like to participate in a discussion about ______" from the FAQ and does not even concern Russian as such.

Comment: @Quassnoi I think it was a valid question, but it needs some editing. There are two questions: who is the authority over the language? who is behind authoritative sources? My answer: RLI is not an authority, it is a _research_ institution, but there are some academically recognized publications which we usually refer to to resolve such questions. Their authors are well-known language researchers. The full answer might include links to online reference materials, references to conteporary publications.

Comment: There are also [справочная служба русского языка](http://www.ruslang.ru/agens.php?id=sprav) и [gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru/) to learn online (both are state-supported).

Comment: @sastanin: it would be a valid question indeed should it not be an invitation to discussion. Let me rephrase this question and make it relevant to the topic of the site.

Comment: Если мне кто-нибудь объяснит, как переводится слово colloquial, я отвечу на этот вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no *de facto* authority over the language. [The Institute of Russian Language](http://www.ruslang.ru/agens.php?id=aims) is just a research institution.

*Update*: As pointed out by @Kira, in [the federal law #53-ФЗ has been passed in 2005](http://docs.pravo.ru/document/view/1470/?search_query=%E2%84%9653-%D0%A4%D0%97+2005). It states that the Russian Goverment may decide on the precedure to define norms and rules of the modern language for use *as a state language* (*1.3. Порядок утверждения норм современного русского литературного языка при его использовании в качестве государственного языка Российской Федерации, правил русской орфографии и пунктуации определяется Правительством Российской Федерации*). In 2006, the Goverment has issued [a decree #714](http://www.rg.ru/2006/11/29/russkij-dok.html), and made the Ministry of Education and Science responsible for creating a list of officially approved dictionaries, grammar compendia, and rules of orthography and punctuation. As of today I cannot find any trace of existence of such a list. Probably it is not ready yet. Even if this list exists, it doesn't cover all the other uses of the language (like personal and business communication, literature, spoken language etc.).

So there is (still) no single language standard.

While there is no single standard, there are many academically recognized publications, which we deem authoritative. Their authors are usually groups of well-known linguists. Newer publications are to be preferred, particularly if you want to learn about modern use of a word.

To learn if a word is colloqial or not, you may just check the dictionary. Many of them are available online. Consider using

- [Яндекс-словари](http://slovari.yandex.ru)
- [dic.academic.ru](http://dic.academic.ru/)
- [www.gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/)

Colloquial words tend to be labeled as *разг.* (разговорное, spoken), *жарг.* (жаргон, slang), or *прост.* (просторечное, uneducated). Sometimes colloquial words become mainstream, so prefer newer dictionaries to judge.

There are also free state-supported services which can answer questions about the language:

- online at [www.gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/)
- by phone, see [Справочная служба русского языка](http://www.ruslang.ru/agens.php?id=sprav)

Comment: -1. Russian language is regulated and the body even can mandate certain usage (such as starting Бог (God) with capital letter after the breakup of the USSR).

Comment: @Anixx There is a body (the Ministry of Education and Science) which may approve dictionaries and other reference materials for official use. I don't know if it approved any. Please note that it doesn't mandate certain usage directly (it approves existing dictionaries and publications), and it doesn't regulate the language beyond its use as a state language (which is the language used by federal bodies, the language of laws, toponyms and documents, public broadcasting and advertising; see #53-FZ 2005 for the complete list).

Answer (score 2):

As from my experience and knowledge, there is institution, which regulates standarts of the Russian language. The rules of the Russian literary language are established by the Russian government.

Here is quotation from the federal state #53:"Порядок утверждения норм современного русского литературного языка при его использовании в качестве государственного языка Российской Федерации, правил русской орфографии и пунктуации определяется Правительством Российской Федерации."

Surely the government asks for assistance groups of linguists, historians of the Russian language, etc.

If the new rule appear, it'll appear first of all in Mass Media, then the corrections will be applied in new dictionaries.

Comment: So with this said, what is the current state of affairs? Do you know if there is a reference that fixes these rules for the practical use? Or do you know if there is an approved and officially recommended source of this information (a recognized dictionary, reference book)?

Comment: @v'-5o-1's73- Yes, there are. Ushakov dictionary, for example. Confusingly, some of the other states also attempt to regulate rules of Russian language. For example, Ukraine mandates use of preposition "в" with the name of their country, Ukraine even though Russian literary norm requires "на". All Ukrainian documents in Russian such as travel declarations use "в". Similarly, in Belarus the law requires the name of the country in Russian to be "Беларусь" even though the Russian norm was "Белоруссия". This parked controversy at a time, but now in seems Russia adopted the Belorussian spelling.

Comment: #53-FZ/2005 states the Government may decide on the procedure to define the rules of the official (_state_) language. Government decree #714/2006 made the Ministry of Education responsible for creating a list of approved reference materials. I don't know if this list exist. So there is a body which may decide which dictionaries and reference materials should be used by the federal bodies (and in some other situations), but it doesn't define the rules of the language, nor it doesn't mandate rules for the non-official language use.

Answer (score -1):

It is absolutely informal matter. It's only about culture, education, good breeding, informal norms and rules shared by society.

Comment: Как страшно жить

Comment: @v'-5o-1's73- Whether a word formal or not is part or its meaning. Why you do not ask, who sets the word's meaning then?

Comment: @anixx, why would I?